# How to register a custom jdbc driver on a computer?

Tags: java, jdbc

My goal here is to eventually develop an installation for Windows, OSX and Linux distributions that will register a custom JDBC driver on the customer's computers, so that they can use it when they are using their favourite SQL tool.

I know some of the tools provide you with a way to manually add a jar, but I was wondering if there is an official way of registering a JDBC driver in each of the operation systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't register a JDBC driver in the operating system, you need to put it on the class path of the application that needs to use the driver.

The `CLASSPATH` environment variable is ignored by most non-trivial Java applications.

Before Java 9, you could try to put the driver in the `lib/ext` folder of the Java installation. But this is **a very bad idea** (eg conflicting dependencies with specific application requirements, etc), and it has been deprecated in Java 8 and removed in Java 9.

How an application configures its class path depends very much on the application: some only use a specific set of jar files and you can't add others, other applications will scan a folder in their application for jar files (so dropping the jar file into that folder will be enough), or require a configuration or launcher file to be changed to add the specific jar file to their class path.

This means that there is no general way to do it.

If you are talking about the automatic driver loading mechanism of JDBC, then look at the documentation of [`java.sql.DriverManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html), specifically about the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file. This still requires that the jar file of the driver is properly added to the class path of the application.

Comment: is there a folder per OS that it is expected to store the jar files in ? or is it completely up to the tool to provide you with a way to find the jar

Comment: @Shachar What part of _"This means that there is no general way to do it."_ don't you understand?

Comment: Mark, I understand that there is no general way of registering a JDBC driver i'm still trying to understand if there are some standards around it, or it is completely up to the jar supplier to determine where to store the jar etc.

Comment: @Shachar The 'jar supplier' has no say in it, you need to conform to the requirements of the application that will need to use the JDBC driver.

Comment: We're planning to create an installation (as the jar supplier) and provide it to customers, for now on OSX for example we plan to store it in:
 /Library/Java/Extensions/some.jar

on windows it yet to be determined,
would it be enough for SQL tools to pick it up from there ?

Comment: @Shachar That will work for Java 8 and earlier, because that is the equivalent of putting things in `lib/ext`, which - as I mention in my answer - is a bad idea, because that can seriously break applications that require a different version of a library. And with Java 9 it will no longer work at all.

Comment: Mark, what do you recommend then? i'm talking about tools like 
https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/

for example.. 
or even mysql workbench which as far as i know does support jdbc drivers other than mysql

Comment: @Shachar Publish your driver to maven central, and maybe include the jar file in your application distribution, but as there is no general way to do it, you will need instruct your users to either check the documentation of the application they want to use, or simply - assuming development cases - to include the dependency just like they would any other JDBC driver.

Comment: DBeaver includes drivers for common database systems, and otherwise you need to include them yourself as documented: https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver/wiki/Admin-Manage-Drivers As far as I'm aware, MySQL Workbench does not support JDBC drivers.

Comment: @Shachar : MySQL Workbench is written in `.NET`. In order to use JDBC, you need JVM.